# Python: print array of strings to stdout line by line

Tags: python, stdout

I need to print to stdout (but next step is print to file) an array of strings, containing the info to build-up a shape.
Below, the for loop:

```
for i in range(0, xMax):
    for j in range(0, yMax):
        print arena_shape[ j + i*yMax]
    print('\r')
```

The array arena_shape[] contains the chars to built-up a 2D figure, figure with i = [0, xMax] rows and j = [0, yMax] columns.
I expect the output to be :

```
i=0    ----------    ------
i=1    |                  |
       |                  |
       |                  |
       |                  |
       |                  |
       |                  |
i=xMax --------------------
```

instead to get the first line `(i=0, j=[0,yMax])` in "horizontal" as I would expect, I get it displayed in vertical, even if I tell python to `\r` only when changing `row i` and not at each `column j`

```
i=0 -
    -
    -
    -
    -
    -
    -
    -
    -
    -




    -
    -
    -
    -
    -
    -
```

I don't understand why this is not changing line after the `print("\r")` instruction.
Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print in Python without newline or space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space)

Comment: What exactly is the issue? To print in python without a newline, just tack a comma (`,`) to the end of the line.

Comment: sorry, I was not clear, I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `print` function in Python always prints in a new line. If you want to print without a new line i suggest storing what you need to print in a temporary variable and printing it only when you exit the inner `for` loop

```
for i in range(0, xMax):
    temp_variable = ''
    for j in range(0, yMax):
        temp_variable += arena_shape[ j + i*yMax]
    print temp_variable
```